# Calculate all the values of $x$ between $0$ and $2\pi$, without using calculator.

Tags: trigonometry

> Calculate all the values of $x$ between $0$ and $2\pi$, without using calculator. $$2\sin 2x=\sqrt2$$

thanks.

Comment: You forgot to show your work...(hint: $\pi > 1$)

Comment: ^Orphaned by the recent edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, now you have $\sin 2x=\frac1{\sqrt2}$. You should know an angle $\theta$ such that $0\le\theta<\pi/2$ and $\sin\theta=\frac1{\sqrt2}$; if it doesn't immediately occur to you, think of the right triangles whose angles you know. There's only one other angle between $0$ and $2\pi$ whose sine is $\frac1{\sqrt2}$; what is it? (It helps here to be familiar with the circle approach to sines and cosines, but you can also get it by considering the graph of $y=\sin x$.)

Comment: The question has changed. Boooooooooooo!

Comment: @TheChaz: Thanks for the ping.

Comment: the answer is $\frac{\pi}{8}$ but I got $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Comment: @SbSangpi: That may be partly my fault: I wrote $\sin x$ instead of $\sin 2x$. You're right that $\sin\frac{\pi}4=\frac1{\sqrt2}$, but that means that $2x=\frac{\pi}4$, and hence $x=\frac{\pi}8$. (Now don't forget the other angle that satisfies the equation.)

Answer (score 1):

$${}{}{}{}{}\varnothing {}{}{}{}$$
*Oh come on!*

The solution to the *revised* question comes from finding angles with a since ratio of $\dfrac{\sqrt2}{2} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt2}$. Write out two periods of such solutions (why?) and then divide the angles by two.

Comment: The original answer must set some sort of record for concision!

Comment: @Brian: Not anymore! (And there is a gold-badged answer of - essentially - one character...inspirational!!)